# Отправка POST запроса на сервер

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest

Начинаю знакомиться с PHP и хочу отправить форму без перезагрузки страницы, вот скрипт:

```
function post(){

    var name = fields[0].value,
        lastname = fields[1].value,
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open('POST', 'setDb.php', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        var gender = radioMan.checked ? "male" : "female";

        xhr.send("name=" + encodeURIComponent(name) +
    "&lastname=" + encodeURIComponent(lastname) + "&gender=" + encodeURIComponent(gender));

    //Проверка ответа от сервера
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if(xhr.status == 200) {
                alert(xmlhttp.responseText);

            }
        }
}
```

- setDb.php php скрипт, который будет записывать данные в БД, сейчас скрип в скрипте содержится инструкция echo, которая должна вывести имя переданное на сервер из формы

  ```
  <?php
  echo $_POST["name"];
  ?>
  ```

Дело в том, что не могу получить ответ от сервера, xmlhttp.responseText = 0;
Что делаю не так?

Comment: На момент выполнения ваших проверок ответа сервера, этот ответ еще не поступил: метод `XMLHttpRequest.send()` выполняется асинхронно, то есть он сразу возвращает управление вызвавшему коду, без блокировки ожиданием результата запроса. Для того чтобы реагировать на ответ сервера, нужно прослушивать событие `readystatechange` (о том как это делать назначением обработчика через свойство объекта - читайте в ответе @Igor. Более современный и рекомендуемый вариант - использовать метод `addEventListener()`, о котором можно прочесть на MDN).

Answer (score 1):

Проверять ответ следует в обработчике события `onreadystatechange`:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    alert(xhr.responseText);
  }
};
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за помощь, вот код который решил мою проблему

```
function post(){

    var name = fields[0].value,
        lastname = fields[1].value,
        gender = radioMan.checked ? "male" : "female",
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open('POST', 'setDb.php', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');


        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            //Проверка ответа от сервера
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                    if(xhr.status == 200) {
                        alert(xhr.responseText);

                    }
                }
        };

        xhr.send("name=" + encodeURIComponent(name) +
    "&lastname=" + encodeURIComponent(lastname) + "&gender=" + encodeURIComponent(gender));


}
```